# Hiding items in React through states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want when I press the button in the Button Component everything in the 'li section' disappears as well as in the ImageComponent but it not working I would like to know what my mistake is. ButtonComponent is rendered somewhere else.

```
App Component/Parent

function App({ hideButton }) {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ImageComponent hideButton={hideButton} />
        </div>

    );
}


// ButtonComponent

function ButtonComponent() {

    const [hideButton, setHideButton] = React.useState(false)

    function handleClick() {
        setHideButton(true)
    }

    return (
        {
            !hideButton && (
                <li>
                    <img className="image"src="./icons/>
                    <Button  onClick={handleClick}   variant="outlined" className="button__rightpage" >Hide</Button>
                    <caption className="text"> Hide</caption>
                </li >
            )
        }
    )
}




// ImageComponent
const ImageComponent = ({ hideButton }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                !hideButton && (
                    <div>
                        <img src='icons/icon.png' />
                        <caption>Image </caption>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You set the `hideButton` state variable in the `ButtonComponent` but pass it to the `ImageComponent` from the `App` component which doesn't have access to the state variable. You need to define the state variable at the `App` component, and pass the state variable and `setHideButton` to the `ButtonComponent`.

Comment: @BlackMath still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to lift up the state to the most parent Component be accessible to the `ButtonCommponent` and the `ImageComponent`. in this Case `App Component`. however, if the ButtonComponent is rendered out of the hierarchy under the `App Component` tree, you should use the context API.

create a context and share the state on it and it will be accessible on the application level.

```
//#1. create context.
export const HiddenContext = React.createContext(false);

//#2. create the provider and share the state with it.
function HiddenProvider({ children }) {
  const [hideButton, setHideButton] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setHideButton(true);
  }

  return (
    <HiddenContext.Provider value={{ hideButton, handleClick }}>
      {children}
    </HiddenContext.Provider>
  );
}


//#3. render the provider component to the most top parent component
export default function App() {
  const { hideButton } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);

  return (
    <HiddenProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <ImageComponent hideButton={hideButton} />
        <OtherComponentRenderTheButton />
      </div>
    </HiddenProvider>
  );
}

// other component that render the button
function OtherComponentRenderTheButton() {
  return <ButtonComponent />;
}

//ButtonComponent

function ButtonComponent() {
  const { hideButton, handleClick } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!hideButton && (
        <li>
          <img className="image" src="./icons" alt="" />
          <Button
            onClick={handleClick}
            variant="outlined"
            className="button__rightpage"
          >
            Hide
          </Button>
          <caption className="text"> Hide</caption>
        </li>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// ImageComponent
const ImageComponent = () => {
  const { hideButton } = React.useContext(HiddenContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {!hideButton && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <img src="icons/icon.png" alt="" />
          <caption>Image </caption>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-elgamal-xrnd9)